# identification of this flower

Tags: botany, species-identification

I saw this flower in Pulau Ubin in Singapore. Can anyone identify the species of this flower?

[image]

Comment: Looks like some type of oleander.

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed the Nerium oleander.. For more info refer to [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oleander) and also [this](http://www.clemson.edu/extension/hgic/plants/landscape/shrubs/hgic1079.html)